# In C# is there a way to convert a linked list to a string?

Tags: c#, linked-list

In C# is there a way to convert a linked list to a string?

I have a linked list of sentences and another linked list of words.
I want to check the sentences linked list for the words in the words linked list and was thinking a good approach would be to convert the words linked list to a string.

Also considering using a nested while loop.

Comment: Probably not the right approach. You probably need something like `sentences.Where(s => words.Any(s.Contains))`

Comment: Maybe compile the words list to an reg expression and iterate over the sentence list to find matched pattern.

Comment: Can you share what you tried so far?

Comment: The [built-in `LinkedList<T>` class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.linkedlist-1) implements `IEnumerable<T>`; the `string.Join` method has an overload which accepts `IEnumerable<T>`. Why can't you just pass your list to `string.Join`?

Comment: Also, LinkedList is rarely the best datastructure to use. A regular List is better in the vast majority of cases. [This question explains why](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34170566/bjarne-stroustrup-says-we-must-avoid-linked-lists), it is for c++, but the same is true for c#.

Answer (score 0):

> was thinking a good approach would be to convert the words linked list to a string.

Any time you have a list of X and a list of Y, and you want to check whether any of the elements in X are in Y, what you need is probably a hash set (not a list)

Hashsets offer fast lookups of fixed values. Your algorithm should be:

- load the list of searching-for into the set
- enumerate the list of searching-in, repeatedly asking if the current item is in the set

```
    var hs = listOfWords.ToHashSet();

    foreach(var sentence in listOfSentences){
      foreach(var word in sentence.Split()){
        if(hs.Contains(word))
        {
          ...
        }
      }
    }
```

or in a LINQ flavored approach

```
    var hs = listOfWords.ToHashSet();

    var result = listOfSentences.Where(sentence=> 
       sentence.Split().Any(word => 
           hs.Contains(word)
       )
    );
```

Caution: c# hashing of strings is, be default, case sensitive and every character contributes to string equality. For a word list of `"hello","world","foo","bar"` and a list of sentences of: `"Hello world!", "Foo bar."` - these sentences do NOT contain any of the words in the word list. `Hello` is not equal to `hello`, `world!` is not equal to `world`. Carefully process your sentences so you are comparing apples with apples - e.g. strip punctuation, and make case equal, for example